# Execute action in web server without client request

Tags: ruby, webserver, sinatra

I am working on Sinatra single purpose application which is making api calls to some service. I would like if server could perform that action at predetermined time and have results stored for client when requested.

Right now I refresh only on user request as:

```
class App < Sinatra::Base
get '/data' do
  if time_to_update
    make_external_api_call
  end
  send_data
```

I would like to separate the two. Move if time_to_update into separate function and execute it every hour so route '/data/ would look like

```
get'/data' do
  send_data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what you need is to set a cron job:

> The software utility Cron is a time-based job scheduler in Unix-like computer operating systems. People who set up and maintain software environments use cron to schedule jobs (commands or shell scripts) to run periodically at fixed times, dates, or intervals.

[Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)

**Hard way**

In order to do so, you need to extract your code that suppose to be executed periodically to Rake task, and configure `cron` to execute it properly.

Example for ubuntu would be to run in terminal:

```
$ crontab -e
```

Which open a file to edit, where you are defining your jobs. You can use something like that:

```
0 * * * * cd <path/to/your/project> && rake <your_task_name>
```

**Easy way**

You may use gem [whatever](https://github.com/javan/whenever). For better explanation of using it, check this [rails cast episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby).

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for whatever. That was along the lines of my thinking and my friend told me the same thing: set URL that will grab the data and use cron to schedule jobs that use curl or wget to call those endpoints to get the data.